# Integrate 2 themes in Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have 2 portals: customer and admin portals and I want to integrate 2 different themes in both portal.

Is there a way to implement 2 themes in my app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234023/share-angular-5-variables-with-scss/49234806#49234806 take a look at this.

Comment: Are you using Angular Material? Could you add more code? What have you done?

Comment: The difference between them is only colors? or are they completely different?

Comment: they are totally completely different themes

Comment: it's like that?
https://angular-multi-layout-example.stackblitz.io/

Comment: @RafaelFerreira is this 2 different themes???

Comment: yep, check this article: http://www.tech-coder.com/2017/01/multiple-master-pages-in-angular2-and.html